# Python type hinting NDJSON

Tags: python, type-hinting

I would like to use type hinting for my python functions.
One takes Newline Delimited JSON as input and another has NDJSON as output.
Is there a specific type hint for JSON or NDJSON?

Or is it just a string? What options do I have here for type hinting?

Example of my "string" looks as follows:

```
{"Employee": "Sander", "ID": 3}
{"Employee": "Someone else", "ID": 5}
```

Example of my function:

```py
def get_ndjson(employees_dicts_list) -> NDJSON:
    employee_data = [json.dumps(employee) for employee in employees_dicts_list]
    return "\n".join(employee_data)
```

Comment: As far as the type system is concerned it's just a string.

Comment: It's just a string. Remember, it's type hinting, not content hinting.

Answer (score 1):

From the [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) documentation:

> Serialize `obj` to a JSON formatted `str` using this conversion table.

So your `employee_data` is a `list` of `str` and the returned value is just a `str`.